# Change default compression levels for file-roller?

Tags: centos, gnome

I'm using gnome on cent OS and have installed file-roller but i want to store my files in uncompressed archives there doesn't seem to be a compression selection within the UI but i read that there's a file you can edit to change the default compression levels.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Either:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/file-roller/general/compression-level "'maximum'"
```

Or:

```
$ dconf-editor
```

1. Select `org` in the left-hand pane.
2. Select `gnome` in the left-hand pane.
3. Select `file-roller` in the left-hand pane.
4. Select `general` in the left-hand pane.
5. Select `compression-level` in the right-hand pane.
6. Set `compression-level` to `'maximum'`.

Unfortunately, you cannot fine-tune this setting for different compression programmes. If you want all the freedom, you can use your shell instead.

[image: Image of dconf Editor with file-roller's compression-level set to maximum.]